# adding https:// prefix for rendering images using html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have links to images in a datafile that are connected to variable called image using key-value pairs. I want these images to render when I'm calling them from my html file. However the image link in the data is missing the https:// prefix. How can i add it using html?

Comment: richmedia.channeladvisor.com/ImageDelivery/imageService?profileId=52000717&imageID=117066&recipeName=180x180

Comment: Maybe you should show your code on how you are rendering it in your post...

Comment: ^^ the link that i'm trying to render

Comment: And that does not help

Comment: <link url="{ $product.link() }" on-click="{ $product.onClick }">
   <img riot-src="//{ $product.data.image }" alt="" /> 
    </link>

Comment: test with this <img riot-src="{'https://'+$product.data.image }" alt="" />

Comment: @godie still doesn't render the image gives the same error

Comment: try to use exactly like this: `"https://" + \`${product.data.image}\``

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
<img riot-src="//{ $product.data.image }" alt="" />
```

to

```
<img riot-src="https://{ $product.data.image }" alt="" />
```